# Using python and selenium to click a button on a web page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWmlL.png)

So I'm trying to connect to https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/ and press the good button which is 3/4;s of the way down.

Using Selenium I've tried to use the get_element(By.xpath) and other attributes, when looking at inspect I dont see what I can use as the bottons look the exact same in config.

should I be using JavaScript to execute the click? how would you go about selecting them with them seeming to share the same attributes. what would be the code to click good and what would it be to click bad, I assume its [0] or [1] is some form of Js?

used selenium attributes, I used By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]'

as that seemed as it should work, but I receive.
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future, please do not post links to images. Post images inline within the question/answer and any code between backticks `\``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button_class = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser').select('div', class_='button-group')[0].button['class']
button_class = ' '.join(button_class)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//button[@class='{button_class}']"))).click()
```

Comment: \venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

seems to time out, so i guess it doesnt seen good within the text? ps thanks for fast response!!

Comment: @pythonrules01 updated my code to search not by ID, but by class. Class is being read by BF4 (because it may be dynamic) then selenium uses that class to find and click button.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the element ID, it is best to search the element by ID:

```py
goodButton = browser.find_element(By.ID,"__next")
```

This will make sure you always select this element even if it gets displaced from existing location. For example, an advertisement banner is inserted above it.

As a rule of thumb remember that a webpage is expected to have unique ID for any element.

##### Edit:

I checked the page source and couldn't find ID attribute for the "Good"-button.

I suggest to search:

- a button
- that contains the text "Good"

Here's the snippet:

```py
goodButton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Good")]')
```

Comment: If you look on the webpage there is a 2 clickable buttons, good and bad.  They both share the same details other than the full xpath(where i got ID from) where one says button[1] and the other says button[2] so how would I find just the good button by using ID as they both use   "__next"

how do i know im selecting the correct one? thanks for your reply.

Comment: If I remove headless so I see the webpage come up, the button is never pressed. 

if i print out the value of good button it shows a session and an element id 
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e88fc97d80e5d4970f57f24baaee9a7a", element="3e04f1f7-8e69-46d5-b2d7-9dbdc01f81b8")>]

but it doesnt click the button. if i use elementS it only finds the one even though there are 2 buttons with same IDs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears when we launch this URL, it doesn't load the whole page immediately. As you scroll past, the subsequent elements started to load, which includes the *vote* section. Also, the following `div` contains the buttons of interest:

```
<div class="button-group">
   <button type="button" ...>&nbsp;&nbsp;Good</button>
   <button type="button" ...>&nbsp;&nbsp;Bad</button>
</div>
```

And its class name `button-group` appears to be unique. Searching for the element using CSS selector will negate any use of long XPATH strings.

Accordingly, to achieve this, load the page, find document/window dimension for scrolling and scroll half through the document. Find the `div` and bring inxto view. And with this `div`, get the buttons and print their text. And then simply click the first button for *Good*.

Here is the code:

```
def launch_find_vote_buttons(url):
    # create webdriver object
    chrome_srv = Service(driver_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_srv,options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    # find doc/win height to get page count for scolling
    doc_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    win_height = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight")
    num_pages = int(doc_height / win_height * 0.5)
    print(f'doc height=>{doc_height}\tpages =>{num_pages}')
    # scroll up to midway of the document
    for page in range(num_pages):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", win_height * (page+1))
        print(f'\tscrolling to=>{win_height * (page+1)}')
        sleep(2)
    
    # find enclosing div and scroll to view
    div_elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="button-group"]')
    div_elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # find button within div and display their text
    buttons = div_elem.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'button')
    for i,btn in enumerate(buttons):
        print(f'button {i} is {btn.text}')
    # click Good button - commented :)
    # buttons[0].click()
```

And here is a sample run:

```
>>> launch_find_vote_buttons('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/')
doc height=>4288    pages =>3
    scrolling to=>622
    scrolling to=>1244
    scrolling to=>1866
button 0 is   Good
button 1 is   Bad
```